Как отслеживать закрытие Telegram Web App?
Нужно отслеживать закрытие telegram web app на мобильниках.
Пробовал:
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {`...`})

window.addEventListener('unload', (event) => {`...`})

window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (event) => {`...`})

Ничего не срабатывает на мобильных устройствах.
Почитал документацию. В ней нет нужного события, которое можно отловить.

Как вариант:
<script>Telegram.WebApp.MainButton
        .setText('CLOSE WEBVIEW')
        .show()
        .onClick(function(){ webviewClose(); });
</script>

<div id="buttons" style="margin-top:100px;">          
<button onclick="webviewClose();">Close</button>
</div>


Решение неплохое, но мне нужно отслеживать закрытие именно через встроенную кнопку в сам телеграмм

declare global {
interface Window {
Telegram: {
WebApp: {
close: () => void;
}
};
}
}

это функция для того чтобы закрыть , а еще она для typescript. мне нужно отслеживать закрытие приложения со встроенной кнопки telegram.
